# How can I find subnet mask given a network ID

Tags: networking, subnet

How can I figure out what the subnet mask is supposed to be given a network ID? Network ID: 210.107.189.0
Subnets required: 2

I am trying to study for the Network+ certification and was looking into subnetting practice found here:
https://www.nybi.org/subnet-1.php

any help is appreciated

Comment: See the excellent answer to [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/7106/8499).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have the latest octet to play with, you can have 2 /25 networks.

- 210.107.189.0/25 (from .1 to .126 addressable)
- 210.107.189.128/25 (from 129 to 254 addressable)

Comment: You are assuming a `/24` network, but that may not be the case.